# Analyze Data c#

Tags: c#

I'm in an intro to c# class, and our resources suck.

I have already input a csv file using StreamReader, what i want to do is analyze the info for a certain characteristic. what confuses me is how do i let my program know to select certain parts of the data from each line? lets say i want to choose the largest number

for example if one line is:

2003-04-12, 334, 367, 289

would i add in a statement to do so here?:

```
input = reader.ReadLine(); 
while (input != null) 
{
    ...
    input = reader.ReadLine(); //next row
}
reader.Close();
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you _want_ to do a comparison for each line in the file while reading it (which is slow) or, can you dump out the whole file _and then_ parse it looking for the pattern you gave example of above?  Does the data always follow the pattern you gave us?

Comment: hey brian, i'd like to do a  comparison for each line, each line has the same data format with different numbers. the first is a date

Comment: If it follows that pattern specifically, I would use a [Regular Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

[Using Regex to capture groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) is probably what you are looking for.

Something like this:

```
var lineRegex = new Regex(@"(?<year>[0-9]+)\-(?<month>[0-9]+)\-(?<day>[0-9]+), (?<first>[0-9]+), (?<second>[0-9]+), (?<third>[0-9]+)");
// ...
var matches = lineRegex.Matches(input);
```

Your results are now in the matches element's collections. This is just an example though, creating the correct Regex string is a task in it's own right.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is a) split the line into parts and b) parse the parts into numbers safely using `.TryParse()`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var reader=System.IO.File.OpenText("Data.csv");
    List<double[]> data=new List<double[]>();
    var line=reader.ReadLine();
    double max=0;
    while(!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        line=reader.ReadLine();
        string[] parts=line.Split(',');
        //parse first part as date
        DateTime date=DateTime.Parse(parts[0]);
        //parse rest of parts as float/doulbe/decimal
        double[] values=new double[parts.Length-1];
        for(int i=0; i<values.Length; i++)
        {
            //for each value in row convert string to number safely.
            double x = 0;
            double.TryParse(parts[i+1], out x);
            values[i]=x;
        }
        //keep data values in list
        data.Add(values);
        //keep highest from 1st column
        if(values[0]>max) { max=values[0]; }
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: BTW, if you want better speed then try the `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()` method.